# biblatex-apa update appears to print the year of the citation twice

Tags: citing, biblatex, apa-style

biblatex-apa was updated on the 20th and it appears to be broken. All my references now appear as "Smith (20082008)"

This is really weird. Why is this happening? I've gone back to `authoryear-comp` for now. I couldn't find out how to contact the author of biblatex-apa. Does anyone (who is better at reading the guts of tex code) have an idea why this has happened? It seems like it's probably a really easy fix...

Also, there's a really quirky aspect to this problem when there's two years (as like when you want to cite the third edition, but also mention when the first edition was published: Kuhn (1996[1962]) shows up as Kuhn (1996[1962][1962]1996). That's just *strange*

Comment: Contacting the author: at the beginning of the documentation the author states his e-mail address.

Comment: Huh. How did I miss that? I've emailed him now...

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with my version of `biblatex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is solved by updating biblatex and biblatex-apa to the newest versions. And complying with the new requirements of biblatex-apa. e.g. explicit `\DeclareLanguageMapping` is needed.